# messagebox.show error/ no overload for method 'show' takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#, messagebox

I'm trying to show a MessageBox but i'm getting the error: 
**no overload for method 'show' takes 1 arguments**.
I cant seem to find a solution in any forum (stackoverflow,msdn...) and I have tried everything that has been suggested. What am I missing?
Any help is appreciated.

BTW. I'm new to windows forms and c# in general but I have written this from a tutorial and it should work.

This is the complete code:

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using NetworksApi.TCP.CLIENT;
using System.IO;
namespace AdvancedClientChat
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Client client;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBoxIP.Text !="" &&  textBoxName.Text !="" && textBoxPort.Text !="")
            {
                client = new Client();
                client.ClientName = textBoxName.Text;
                client.ServerIp = textBoxIP.Text;
                client.ServerPort = textBoxPort.Text;
            }
            else
            {
              MessageBox.Show("You must fill all the boxes");
            }
        }

        private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void MessageBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a control named `MessageBox` which is causing your problems. Either rename the control, or you will have to specify the `MessageBox` class with its full namespace, `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("myMessage");`

```
        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBoxIP.Text !="" &&  textBoxName.Text !="" && textBoxPort.Text !="")
            {
                client = new Client();
                client.ClientName = textBoxName.Text;
                client.ServerIp = textBoxIP.Text;
                client.ServerPort = textBoxPort.Text;
            }
            else
            {
              System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You must fill all the boxes");
            }
        }
```